# Merge tables cell by cell

Tags: r

Given these two tables

```
a <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
b <- data.frame(a=c(7,8,9),b=c(10,11,12))
```

I would like to obtain a third table by combining a and b cell by cell like this:

```
  a   b
1 1,7 4,10
2 2,8 5,11
3 3,9 6,12
```

Comment: try `as.data.frame(sapply(1:ncol(a), function(i) paste(a[,i], b[,i], sep=',')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on what you want to do with the result. Here are a couple of versions:

```
data.frame(Map("paste", a, b, sep=","))
    a    b
1 1,7 4,10
2 2,8 5,11
3 3,9 6,12
```

which returns two columns of factor variables. You can add strings asFactors=FALSE to get character variables instead, as in

```
data.frame(Map("paste", a, b, sep=","), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

or to put them into separate columns with similar names.

```
cbind(a, b)[c(1,3,2,4)]
  a a.1 b b.1
1 1   7 4  10
2 2   8 5  11
3 3   9 6  12
```

or, more programmatically

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, Map(cbind, a, b))
  a.1 a.2 b.1 b.2
1   1   7   4  10
2   2   8   5  11
3   3   9   6  12
```